# netStream Client.onMetaData not receiving width/height

Tags: height, width, undefined, netstream

I am streaming flv video,everything works fine, but client I have added to netStream 
is receiving (via onMeatData function) only these parameters

```
canSeekToEnd, 
audiocodecid, 
duration, 
videocodecid,
```

If it is not possible to get width and height from metadata how I can get them?

Answer (score 0):

Think it's better not to rely on MetaData. But I don't know, is it possible to access width/height from flashplayer.

You can add missing w/h into flv files with [FLVTool2](http://www.inlet-media.de/flvtool2/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you actually get the metadata listener to respond? Like, does it show your traces from it?

I ask because some frameworks seem to prohibit